# how to show errors of validate() in Play Java

Tags: java, validation, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.0 for java

```
public String email;
public String validate(){

    if(email!= null &&(email.endsWith("@xyz.com") )){
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println("error");
    return "Please Add valid xyz  email id only ";
}
```

above is my code for validation of email

my question is how to show "Please Add valid xyz  email id only" in the form if user error a wrong email id

I tried

```
@helper.inputText(playerForm("email"), '_label -> "Email",'_help -> "Must be xyz id",   
    '_showConstraints -> false,
    '_showErrors -> true,
    '_error -> playerForm.error("email")
)
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the answer.**
It goes to global error 
you can get it through

```
@if(form.hasGlobalErrors) {
   <div class="alert alert-error">@form.globalError.message</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer another solution, there are three versions of the validate() method you can use depending on your needs. You're using the simplest in which you simply return 'NULL' or a 'String' error message. The other two versions allow you to specify multiple errors on specific fields (so they don't go to the "global" error map.

```
public List<ValidationError> validate(){
  ...
}

public Map<String, List<ValidationError>> validate(){
  ...
}
```

As with the `String` version, you simply return `NULL` if there are no errors. If you do have errors then you populate a `List` or `Map` with one or more errors. The map version allows you to specify errors on multiple fields.

```
new ValidationError("email", "Please add valid xyz email id only.");
```